# Ошибка при запуске приложения python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[image: Ошибка]

Я скомпилировал код в виртуалке 32 бит windows 7, т.к. у моего друга тоже 32 бит, кинул ему, а у него такая ошибка, у меня ее нет ни на виртуалке ни на основе (64 бит), пробовал компилировать разными версиями python (3.6.1(на котором писал) и 3.5.3(на нее хотел перейти из-за некоторых модулей)). Компилировал PyInstaller, через --onefile. Вот код:

```
import socket
from time import sleep

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 1080))
sock.send(input().encode())

data = sock.recv(1024)
while not data:
    sleep(0.1)

sock.close()

print(data.decode())
input("Press any key to exit...")
```

Кидал ему чтобы проверить соединение через socket, а так же мои порты

Comment: Проблемы была в антивирусе IObit Malware Fighter, он блокировал доступ программе к библиотекам. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Судя по тому что вы говорите в прошедшем времени, мне страшно представить что вы сделали с антивирусом :)

Comment: Отключил и все заработало сразу же :) Может можно как-то скомпилировать без файла base-library.zip (или как его там), на него антивирус и ругался..

Comment: Удалите антивирус и не пользуйтесь другим, как по мне бесполезное явление..

Answer (score 0):

Причина была в антивирусе, блокировал доступ к файлу.